# Find the angle θ, such that...

Tags: trigonometry

a) sinθ=0.8

b) cos2θ=-0.24

c) tanθ/2=2.1

We are allowed to use calculators to solve these kinds of questions, but I have problems of showing them with a general solution. That's what I've done:

a) sinθ=0.8

θ=53.13° +360° =k

θ=-53.13° +360° =k

b) COSθ= -0.24

θ=51.94°+360 °=k

θ=-51.94°+360°=k

c) tanθ/2=2.1

tanθ=4.2

θ=76.60 °

θ=76.60 °+360 °=k

Just not sure if I am doing the right things :/

Comment: $0.8$ became $0.5$ in $a)$

Answer (score 0):

a) Look at the unit circle where the line $y=0.8$ intersects the circle. Or consider that $\sin(-θ)=-\sin(θ)$.

b) the sign of $\cosθ$ is positive for $θ$ between $-90°$ and $90°$.

c) check if it is $\tan(θ)/2$ or $\tan(θ/2)$.